# Django: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'

Tags: python, django

In my forms.py I have a custom ModelForm that contains a `save()` method:

```
def save(self):
    bus = super().save(commit=False)

    datei = self.upload.name

    original_dateiname = datei.name
    extension = original_dateiname.split('.')[-1]

    a = Datei.objects.create(file=datei, original_dateiname=original_dateiname, extension=extension)

    self.datei = a

    bus.save()
    return bus
```

However, now I get the error:
`save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'`

What's wrong here?

Comment: `save()` method has no argument `commit`

Comment: default arguments are `force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None`

Comment: @Jerin no, that is the model save method. OP said this was the form.

Answer (score 1):

You have redefined the save method so that it no longer takes a commit argument, but you are still passing one when you save the form in your view. You should accept the argument and use it to determine whether to save the object to the db.

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    bus = super().save(commit=False)
    ...
    if commit:
        bus.save()
    return bus
```

Answer (score 1):

You've overridden the save method, but you haven't preserved its signature. Yo need to accept the same arguments as the original method, and pass them in when calling super.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save((*args, **kwargs)
    ...
```